# Scala 2.8 weird type error

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Types:

```
def radioGroup[T](values: Array[T], textProvider: T => String)(setups:(RadioGroup[T] => Unit)*)(parent: Composite): RadioGroup[T]
def label(setups:(Label => Unit)*)(parent:Composite): Label

def contains(setups : (Composite => Unit)*) : Composite // "Pimp my library" on Composite
```

This works:

```
new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE).contains(
  label() // should have type Composite => Label
)
```

This doesn't:

```
new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE).contains(
  radioGroup(Array(1,2), (_:Int).toString)() 
   // should have type Composite => RadioGroup[Int]
)
```

with the following error:

```
polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : => (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite) => main.scala.RadioGroup[Int]
required: (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite) => Unit
```

I can annotate the return type of `radioGroup` to be `Unit`, but I don't understand 1) how the cases of `radioGroup` and `label` can be different; 2) why is there an extra arrow at the beginning of the "found" type in the error message.

Comment: Im assuming the second `)` after `.toString` is a typo?

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug.  Have you reported it to the Scala bug tracker?

Comment: Another interesting note is that this works `contains(radioGroup(Array(1,2), (_:Int).toString)()(_))`. I'm still looking into why but I'm not certain yet.

Comment: Also discussed at http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_frm/thread/94ee76c3fa18961e

Comment: The bug report is [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4336)